# Slow Mac Download Compared to Windows on Mac on Network

Tags: cisco, ethernet

We have Mac (there is no difference what the OS version, is, it gives the same results) end users who are experiencing slow Mac download on the LAN. When a download is started, the download time for the file keeps going up and takes a really long time before the download is finished. Sometimes, the download just times out. Our users using Windows don't experience this issue. The Macs are connected by Ethernet. Even when the Mac is connected to Wifi, the dowload still behaves like when it's connected to Ethernet. When a download is done off the network with the Mac, it downloads fine with no issues. The issue seems to be in our network causing the Mac download issues but we can't seem to figure out what it is or where to look to troubleshoot to figure out what might be causing it. Any help troubleshooting this would be greatly appreciated. What are some possible things that can cause slow Macs download issue on the LAN? I don't understand why it's only affecting Mac machines and not Windows machines.

Initially, I thought it might be a host configuration on the Mac (Mountain Lion OS X 10.8.5) causing the issue so I formatted the drive and installed El Capitan but the download time was the same. I then did a packet capture on the Mac and on the Windows to try to compare what might be causing it but I am not quite familiar with how to analyze packet captures. From looking at the captures with the little knowledge i know, I can see some connection resets between the two.I have even also done a packet capture on the Mac off the network to try to see what it might be doing different during the download off the network. Is there a way that I can post a snip-it of the captures so someone can help me analyze the it to see what might causing it on the network?

Comment: Does it happen with a specific website or any download from the Internet? Do you have a proxy in place? like sysadmin suggested, check the trace files or upload it if possible. I would try to use a different Internet connection with the MACs, maybe a test DSL line isolated from the enterprise network. Try a different web browser or download client.

Comment: This happens to any download from the internet. I have tried using a different browser (Chrome and Firefox) but still with the same results. This doesn't happen when I get off the network and do a download. I am able to download on the Mac with no issues when I am off the network. When i connect to the Mac to the wifi on the network, i experience the download issue. How do I upload the the trace file on here? maybe you can help me analyze it. I am not really familiar with analyzing packet captures.

Comment: I am not sure how to upload it here (sorry, I am new to this site) but you can try google drive or dropbox and share the link? Do you have a proxy server (like bluecoat) on your enterprise network? What does your LAN topology looks like? i.e Mac--Switch--Router--Proxy--Firewall--Edge--ISP?

Comment: For the LAN, we have Mac >Connected to switch > Connected to Router > Connected to Firewall > Internet. We do have a proxy server but its on the DMZ. Below is an example of the interface config on the switch that I am using to troubleshoot: interface GigabitEthernet5/0/23
switchport mode access
switchport voice vlan 2
srr-queue bandwidth share 1 25 70 5
srr-queue bandwidth shape 3 0 0 0
queue-set 2
priority-queue out
spanning-tree portfast
service-policy input IPPHONE+PC
end

Comment: And to add, we have not made any changes to the network. We do have web filtering configured on the network and port mirroring for the web filtering as well.

Answer (score 1):

The closest we have to a packet-capture snippeting service is likely CloudShark.

The resets are interesting, and can be a cause of your perceived slowness on the OS X machines. To explain why, we have to get into a bit of detail about how speeds are selected. This is based in [TCP Sliding Windows](http://www.tcpipguide.com/free/t_TCPSlidingWindowAcknowledgmentSystemForDataTranspo.htm), with a side order of [bandwidth delay product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bandwidth-delay_product).

Absolute throughput of a given network connection is determined by a few factors:

- How fast packets can transmit.
- How long packets take to get where they're going.
- How much data the sending party is willing to leave outstanding (unacknowledged).

A 1GbE connection spanning the US has around 80ms of one-way latency on it. Since acknowledgments are a factor here, we have to count their return time. So, make that 160ms Round Trip Time. A 1GbE connection can have 20MB of data 'outstanding' in those 160ms (1024Gb x .16 seconds) if it is transmitting at full speed.

When a TCP connection is negotiated, one of the parameters both sides handshake on is the size of the TCP window. This is the third bullet point: how much data the sending party is willing to leave unacked versus the receiving party's buffer sizes to receive data. As data is transmitted, both parties issue updates about how big of a window they're willing to tolerate. For fast, clean networks, this can get pretty large.

But, if the connection is reset for some reason, the process starts anew with the original window sizes. If the window is full, the sending side will stop sending until those ACKs get back to it. You begin to see why getting connection-resets can cause performance issues.

---

There is another side of this that I want to mention, as I've seen it cause this kind of problem before. You didn't mention you saw it, but if you look you may see them. Retransmits.

One of the additions to TCP from the initial specification is [Selective Acknowledgements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol#Selective_acknowledgments). This comes into play if there are packet drops, not connection resets. Without SACKs, If that 1Gb, 160ms RTT connection I mentioned before has a packet drop, the receiving party will sit there and drop 20MB of data on the floor before the sending party resends everything from the dropped packet forward. This kind of behavior was fine for the kind of networks we had in 1989, but our current ones are a lot faster and fatter. SACKs allow the receiving party to say, "I've seen up to timestamp 123, and 125-137", which allows the sending party to only retransmit the missing 124 segment and get on with the rest of it.

I have *definitely* seen cases where lacking SACK support on a connection results in simply terrible throughputs. Once we got them enabled on both sides, performance went up to theoretical-max.

The clue for this problem is found in the initial TCP 3-way handshake. You should see SACK in the Options header on both sides. If the OSX machines aren't issuing it, but Windows does, you have a big clue to your problem.

Comment: Note for the pedants: the latencies used here are for example only. One case I worked had a 43ms one-way ping time, confirmed multiple ways, and yet behaved like it had a 1600ms RTT. Why? Only Turing and Murphy know, but it probably had something to do with buffers. The packet-loss rates on that connection kept throughput maxed to ~1.4MB/s until we got the SACK problem addressed.

Comment: From looking at the captures, I do see packet re-transmissions.. How do I go about improving the SACK that is if the issue is related to that?

Comment: First off, figure out which side lacks it (probably the OS X machines). Then figure out why it's not there. Some firewalls strip that option as potentially abusive, so that's one place to look. Next, check the OSX network settings to see how to enable it. I don't have any in my stable, so I can't guide you to it. It's an advanced setting, so may be hidden pretty well.

Comment: I checked the packet captures for both the Mac and Windows and under the Transmission Control Protocol for the Mac capture, there is an "Option"  dropdown but there is no SACK and the packet capture for the Windows there is no "Option" under the Transmission Control Protocol

Comment: @KenniG It would be on the SYN and SYN,ACK packets. The SYN packet should have an option of `SACK_PERM=1`, and so should the SYN,ACK packet.  If it's not there on both, selective acks are not enabled on that connection.